# Core brige is not working in ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, activemq-artemis

I have created a core bridge in ActiveMQ Artemis to send data from my local Artemis server to a remote Artemis server.

When I'm trying to send messages to remote server no error is happening, but no data will be send to the remote server.
Just after I stop my local server and restart it, I can see data in remote server.
In the other words, I can the message will be stored in remote server just after restarting local Artemis server.

```
  <connectors>
     <!-- Connector to the other node -->
     <connector name="remote-connector">tcp://192.168.100.33:61616</connector>
  </connectors>
  <bridges>
     <bridge name="my-bridge">
        <queue-name>jms.queue.naja</queue-name>
        <forwarding-address>jms.queue.naja.dest</forwarding-address>
        <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
        <confirmation-window-size>10000000</confirmation-window-size>
        <static-connectors>
           <connector-ref>remote-connector</connector-ref>
        </static-connectors>
     </bridge>
  </bridges>
```

Comment: What version of Artemis are you using?

Comment: @JustinBertram thanks for your response, artemis V2.7.0

Comment: Can you create a repo on GitHub with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?